# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<UserObj>' when making mongoose query by ID

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, next.js

I have the following API route in Next:

```
import {NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse} from "next";
import dbConnect from "../../utils/dbConnect";
import {UserModel} from "../../models/user";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method !== "GET") return res.status(405);
    if (!req.query.id || Array.isArray(req.query.id)) return res.status(406).json({message: "No ID found in request"});

    try {
        await dbConnect();

        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.query.id });

        if (!user) return res.status(404).json({message: "No user found"});
        
        return res.status(200).json({data: user});
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: e});
    }
}
```

Typescript says that the line `const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.query.id });` contains error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<UserObj>'`. Creating an `ObjectId` instead of a string (`const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.id) });`) throws the same error.

I've looked through the type files/docs but I'm struggling to figure out why this is invalid. Shouldn't querying by ID with a string or ObjectId be a valid condition object? Querying by other fields works fine.

Why is this invalid, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .findByID for id based queries.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution by [@Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270311/tim) is good and solves this punctual situation, but it doesn't get you to the root of the problem. What if you have to use the `findOne` method because you are going to use another field in the filter? For example:
You want to get the user with that ***id*** and that the ***deletedAt*** attribute is `null`.

```
const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.query.id, deletedAt: null});
```

You will get the same error cause the mistake is in the `userModel` definition. I guess your user class is basically as shown below:

```
import { ObjectId, Types } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ versionKey: false, timestamps: true })
export class User {
  @Field(() => ID, {name: 'id'})
  readonly _id: ObjectId;

  @Field(() => Date, {nullable: true, name: 'deleted_at'})
  @Prop({type: Date, required: false, default: null})
  deletedAt?: Date;

  @Field()
  @Prop({required: true, index: true})
  name: string;

  ...
}
```

The problem is that you are directly accessing the Schema `user` when you should be accessing the `model` (repository pattern).

**[SOLUTION]**: Create the model or the repository for your user class, and use it to interact with your database.
In my case I just added the following lines:

```
import { ObjectId, Types, Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ versionKey: false, timestamps: true })
export class User {
    ...
}

export type UserDocument = User & Document;
```

OR

```
import { ObjectId, Types, Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ versionKey: false, timestamps: true })
export class User extends Document{
    ...
}
```

and in my service I instantiated an object of type model:

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

private userModel: Model<UserDocument>;
```

and then I was able to make the following method call:

```
...
await dbConnect();
const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.query.id });
if (!user) return res.status(404).json({message: "No user found"});
...
```